# Robust exception handling in console application

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch, console-application

If I put `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` code in console application apart from usual try-catch to catch unhandled exceptions. That means, is it sure that any exception will not force application to terminate in between? 
If not, what type of exceptions are out of scope of it?

Answer (score 0):

No. It means that you will have the chance to run some code *before* your application crashes, but you will not be able to prevent the crash. [Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx):

> This event provides notification of uncaught exceptions. It allows the
>   application to log information about the exception before the system
>   default handler reports the exception to the user and terminates the
>   application.

Trying to make the application "crash-proof" by blindly catching *all* exceptions is a fool's errand: since you don't really know what went wrong, how do you know that it's OK for the program to continue running?

Theoretically speaking, *anything* you do inside the event handler might go wrong in any possible manner (since an unhandled exception was thrown, and you don't know what it is, it could be anything). So not only is it impossible to prevent the application from crashing, but you should also be *very* careful about what you do inside the handler.

Answer (score 0):

No, the application will be terminated anyway, but it gives you a chance to log the exception properly before the application exits. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx

> It allows the application to log information about the exception before the system default handler reports the exception to the user and terminates the application.